# How to login and get token from mobile device in ASP.NET Single Page App (SPA)

Tags: asp.net, authorization, token, single-page-application

When I create default SPA template project VS2013 creates MeController. Calling Get I have a user information if logged in from site. How can I log in and get token from mobile device?
I try

```
POST "/Token?userName=someuser%40gmail.com&password=SomeAlpha%2B12345-Password&grant_type=password"
```

Response is

```
{
"readyState": 4,
"responseText": "{\"error\":\"invalid_client\"}",
"responseJSON": {
    "error": "invalid_client"
},
"status": 400,
"statusText": "Bad Request"
}
```

StartupAuth.cs:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // Enable the application to use OAuthAuthorization. You can then secure your Web APIs
    static Startup()
    {
        PublicClientId = "web";

        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/Account/Authorize"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
    }

    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
        // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
        // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
        // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
    }
```

Comment: Where does it check PublicClientId? and how to add it to request?

Answer (score 1):

I've found answer by myself:

I've overrided ValidateClientAuthentication in ApplicationOAuthProvider class:

```
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider 
{
    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        var clientIdParam = context.Parameters.Get("client_id");
        if (context.ClientId == null && clientIdParam == "mobile"))
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```

Url:

```
POST "/Token"
```

Request body:

```
userName=someuser%40gmail.com&password=SomePassword&grant_type=password&clientId=mobile"
```

Response body:

```
 {"access_token":"6EtSNgXOqI8uN8TXXXXXXXXG2Hd46B2j3A6eOApAm12j","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":1209599,"userName":"someuser@gmail.com",".issued":"Wed, 27 Jan 2016 13:30:25 GMT",".expires":"Wed, 10 Feb 2016 13:30:25 GMT"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the great tutorial for enabling token based auth between WebAPI and any kind of client, in this case client is AngularJS SPA app.

http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Comment: default SPA template uses nockout

Comment: It doesn't matter which spa framework you use. Concept is the same.